# "No such index at level 1" syntax error in simple word locator function

Tags: r

```
string <- "This is a test"
find_words_2 <- function(x){
  words <- strsplit(x, " ")
  l <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(words)) {
    wrd <- words[[i]]
    l[[wrd]] <- c(l[[wrd]], i)
  }
  return(l)
}
find_words_2(string)
```

The function is supposed to create a list with the key being the word and the values the locations of the words. The error I get is "No such index at level 1".

Comment: what are you using for x? When I tried `x <- c("yes", "no")` it worked fine but when I tried `x <- c("yes, no")` it gave me the same error

Comment: x is a string vector with one element. For example a long passage from a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in an unlist for proper scoping, otherwise you are parsing a list of length 1

```
 find_words_2 <- function(x){
      words <- strsplit(x, " ")
      l <- list()
      for (i in 1:length(unlist(words))) {
        wrd <- unlist(words)[i]
        l[[wrd]] <- c(l[[wrd]], i)
      }
      return(l)
    }


    R> x <- "fake text that I am using"
    R> find_words_2(x)
    $fake
    [1] 1

    $text
    [1] 2

    $that
    [1] 3

    $I
    [1] 4

    $am
    [1] 5

    $using
    [1] 6
```

Comment: `unlist(words)` is unnecessary.  Just use `words[[1]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
   words <-"foo bar baz" 
   find_words_2 <- function(x){
      words <- strsplit(x, " ")
      l <- list()
      for (i in 1:length(words[[1]])) {
        wrd <- words[[1]][i]
        l[[wrd]] <- c(l[[wrd]], i)
      }
      return(l)
    }
```

This gives

```
$foo
[1] 1

$bar
[1] 2

$baz
[1] 3
```